# How many dogs are there?

Tags: undertale

One of the things that first attracted me to this game was the promise that it contained "At least 5 dogs." The actual number seemed to be even greater! What is the total number of dogs in Undertale?

Comment: 8.1 as confirmed by TaroNuke!* (*note; probably incorrect)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Six dogs and one creature composed of an unspecified number of dogs.

- Lesser Dog
- Greater Dog
- Doggo
- Dogamy and Dogaressa
- Toby's avatar

  - It's unclear if this is the same dog over and over or different dogs, but they all look exactly the same.
- Endogeny*

Comment: Is Toby's Avatar the "Annoying Dog" from Waterfall?

Comment: @Powerlord No, Toby's Avatar is [southwest of Snowdin](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/237917/how-do-i-open-the-door-southwest-of-snowdin). Also, wouldn't Ice Wolf technically count too?

Comment: @Whaaaaaat Ice Wolf?

Comment: @fredley Just north of Snowdin -- there's that wolf (?) throwing ice into the river.

Comment: @Whaaaaaat That's a wolf, not a dog

Comment: @Powerlord It might be, it might not be, the game doesn't say

Comment: what about the bomb dog from the fight with the robot?

Comment: what about the dogs behind the Mysterious Door?

Comment: Endogeny when Checked: Amalgamate/Endogeny: Its unclear how many dogs this counts as. Also: Endogeny's theme is a variation on "Dogsong", which becomes apparent when it becomes spareable, when the music becomes a slowed down version of Dogsong.

Answer (score -2):

I counted 8 dogs in total:

- endogeny
- annoying dogo (toby's avatar)
- dog amy
- dogaressa
- dogo
- greater dog
- lesser dog
- ice dog thing

  [enter link description here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwic3s2PlOffAhWL7oMKHZXxBwEQjRx6BAgBEAU&url=https%3A%2F%2Fn8r8.wordpress.com%2Ftag%2Fundertale%2F&psig=AOvVaw11pWIu0G0z5YviRgj0KcUf&ust=1547345160562101)

Comment: What that link is about? Is this source?